# Admob's Interstitial impression CTR is high

Tags: java, android, admob

I have an android app with only interstitial ads on it and i am showing them on natural transitions like showing them on bottom view navigation item's onClick and on some specific buttons. I am showing an ad after 4 clicks in my app by maintaining a count. I am getting Impression CTR ranges from 6 to 11. I have over 4k active users. Is that worrying? Please anyone guide me

Answer (score 0):

don’t worry if it’s just ctr of the interstitial ad, just maintain your overall ctr on account level as it should remain around 6%. Although, sometimes even overall ctr can exceed 8% without causing any issue but remaining under it is safe. Admob doesn’t concern about ctr% of any specific ad format. Neither do they monitor specific country-wise ctr%. I’ll recommend you to use small banner ads to keep your ctr% of account balanced as banner ads get lesser clicks. Hope it helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i am currently using only banners and native ads but without interstitials ads i am not getting enough revenue after doing google ads campaign. :(

Comment: No, I meant to say that use banner ad beside interstitial ads to keep ctr% balanced. You must and should use interstitial ads.